# multi table join with apache drill

Tags: mysql, hdfs, apache-drill

I am trying to join one table from mysql and 2 csv files from hdfs, so as a whole I'm trying to join 3 tables using apache drill.

It works when I join mysql table and 1 dfs file, but fails when I try to join 1 mysql table and 2 dfs csv files. Please help.

Here is the code:

```
select CAST(a.Longitude AS DOUBLE),CAST(a.Latitude AS DOUBLE) 
from ((MySQL.dummy.`accident_05_07` as a 
inner join dfs.`/user/drill/accidents_2009_to_2011.csv` as b 
on a.Longitude=CAST(b.Longitude AS DOUBLE)) 
inner join dfs.`/user/drill/accidents_2012_to_2014.csv` as c 
on a.Longitude=CAST(c.Longitude AS DOUBLE))
```

> [Error Id: 90c4ac92-83e9-4b23-bcd9-5c1535cd58ad on
>   inpunpclx1825e.kih.kmart.com:31010]
>   org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: PARSE ERROR:
>   Non-query expression encountered in illegal context SQL Query select
>   CAST(a.Longitude AS DOUBLE),CAST(a.Latitude AS DOUBLE)
>   from((MySQL.dummy.`accident_05_07` as a inner join
>   dfs.`/user/drill/accidents_2009_to_2011.csv` as b on
>   a.Longitude=CAST(b.Longitude AS DOUBLE)) inner join
>   dfs.`/user/drill/accidents_2012_to_2014.csv` as c on
>   a.Longitude=CAST(c.Longitude AS DOUBLE)) ^

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: Edited the question with code.

Comment: Did you find any solution @LelioFaieta

Comment: Also posting error message with stacktrace would be useful to help identify the problem.

Comment: The problem in your query is your extra paranthesis. If you remove them your sql will run. The join will be from the first table to last table in order.

Comment: Ok. I'll try that. Thanx for the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. That solved the error.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT `a`.`Longitude`,`a`.`Latitude` 
FROM ((`MySQL`.`dummy`.`accident_05_07` `a` 
INNER JOIN `dfs`.`/user/drill/accidents_2009_to_2011.csv` `b` 
ON `a`.`Longitude`=`b`.`Longitude`) 
INNER JOIN `dfs`.`/user/drill/accidents_2012_to_2014.csv` `c` 
ON `a`.`Longitude`=`c`.`Longitude`)
```

Comment: Thank you. I had already solved the issue. Thank you for the answer. :)